# NetBeans IDE 10 - synchronize/download/upload missing

Tags: netbeans

I upgraded from NetBeans 8.2 to 10.0. I noticed that the remote synchronisation / download and upload entry is missing in the context menu.

[image]

This is how it looks like in NetBeans 8.2

[image]

Was this feature removed or moved to some other place?

Comment: Any reason you didn't upgrade to the current version 11?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Because I think it is too new and still might need testing. I thought 10 is more stable.

Comment: The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60395911/4684797). It is a user mistake.