# Netbeans 8.2 - synchronise/upload/download missing

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8.2. I noticed that the remote synchronisation / download and upload entry is missing in the context menu suddenly.

[image]

How it should look like:

[image]

I already restarted netbeans. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is arising because you are comparing the context menu on the **Files** tab with the context menu on the **Projects** tab. I see the same thing for a PHP project.

**Projects tab** (with context menu entries):

[image: ProjectsTab]

**Files tab** (without context menu entries):

[image: FilesTab]

I suspect that the menu entries are missing from the context menu on the **Files** tab because [early documentation on the Remote Synchronization feature](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/remote-synchronization-v2) stated "*Please notice that the remote synchronization works better only on the whole project (it means that the Source Files must be selected)*", and you can't select "*Source Files*" from the **Files** tab.